# Setting classpath for a jar and a class

Tags: java, class, classpath

I need to set the classpath for servlet-api.jar and another class in order to compile a file.java. 
How could I accomplish that? I have tried

```
javac -cp /path/to/servlet-api;/home/user/Desktop/Other.class file.java
```

However it does not work.

Any help? I am aware it's possible to set the environment variable however I would like to know if it's possible manually. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath must contain jar files, and directories. Directories must be directories containing the root of a package tree. So, assuming `Other` is in the package `com.foo.bar`, and its class file is `/home/user/Desktop/com/foo/bar/Other.class`, the classpath should be

```
-cp /path/to/servlet-api.jar:/home/user/Desktop
```

Note that `:` is the path separator on Unix. `;` is for Windows. I assume you're not on Windows since your path is `/home/...` and not `c:\home\...`

PS: If Other is not in any package, then fix that. Classes should always be in a package.